# Maintaining multiple standalone ruby scripts on same machine

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemfile

I have one machine which runs multiple standalone ruby scripts. Every time I have to upgrade some gem for one of the scripts, I have to look for its impact on other scripts as well. Do you think it will be a good practice to create one gemfile each for a ruby script or can someone recommend me a better way to maintain such system? I also sometimes want to use different versions of the same gem in different scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [RVM](http://rvm.io) or [RbEnv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)?

In this case, you will need to have each file in a separate folder with rvm/rbenv config.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Denyago. I have considered using rvm and was writing gemfile for each script. but writing it one for each was little cumbersome. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I create independent gemset for each project to be sure that all be ok with gems and it's versions.
[RVM](http://rvm.io) gives all the tools to manage gemsets.

So you will need to create a separate folder for each script with its own `.ruby-gemset` in it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Freemanoid. I am going ahead with RVM now.